# NaN loss occurs with custom loss function, even if gradient is set to 0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-gradient

I've been trying to implement a custom loss function for a TF Estimator, but TensorFlow is returning NaN losses. This occurs even when setting the learning rate to low numbers (1e-10) or 0. When forcefully setting the gradient to 0, the neural network works, implying an issue with the gradients. I have already checked the dataset for NaN values, outliers, etc. In addition, I have attempted to remove any functions that could potentially interfere with the automatic differentiation, to no avail (e.g. map_fn). What else could be causing these problems?

- The loss function does not weight all of the neural network's predictions equally; some predictions are taken into account multiple times when generating the loss
- The loss function also requires features not run through the neural network

Error message:

```
tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.
```

Comment: You're not updating `gvs`. You assigned `nn` some values but that's it. `gvs` is still the same as before.

Comment: @mnis Shoot, you're right! Forcefully setting the gradients to zero allows the estimator to work. Do you know what else could be causing the NaN values?

Comment: that's hard to find without seeing the actual code.

Comment: https://github.com/christopherkang/Cyber-GSSL/blob/master/prop_algs/gell_estimator.py

Comment: The loss function is contained from lines 86-308. For the dataset given, I am only using the unlabeled subloss.